# If statement with function as a condition in Arduino without () works fine

Tags: c++, arduino

I was using function returning bool as a condition in if statement in Arduino:

```
bool conditionFunc(){
 return true;
}
void setup(){}

void loop(){
  if (conditionFunc){
  }
}
```

In my opinion I should do:

```
if (conditionFunc()){ //added ()
  doSometing;
}
```

But the first one didn't cause any error during verifying, and code worked (according to my client - I didn't build a circuit - it was simple job so I didn't have to do it). I found it by accident. I don't have any variable named conditionFunc. In my opinion error should be discovered during verifying in Arduino IDE.

I'm confused. Did I miss something when I was learning c++, and the both solutions are OK? Maybe this is caused by the way c++ is interpreted by Arduino? 
As I said I didn't see it in action, but I don't know why my client would lay about something he wants to work properly. At least it should cause problem during compilation (verification in Arduino IDE)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first converts the function into a function pointer, and tests whether that pointer is non-null. It always is, since every function has a non-null address, so it will always `doSomething`.

So the code will compile, and might appear to "work" if the condition is usually true; but it might go wrong when the condition is false but the program carries on to `doSomething` anyway.